# Android Material CardView with full screen image on Cardview

Tags: android, material-design, android-cardview

i need to do this :

http://developer.android.com/design/material/images/card_travel.png

so i create and add the dependency to the project and here is my activity main code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/feed_detail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="6dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic"/>


        <TextView
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
            android:textColor="#555"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Detail"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

so, how we can do this like below picture:?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0lNa.png

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a translucent status bar. When you have this configured you're able achieve this effect. Make also sure to remove the actionbar as I do in my example down below, otherwise you'll have to make it transparent.

**Change your v21/themes.xml file to this:**

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

Then add *android:fitsSystemWindows="true"* to your LinearLayout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/feed_detail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
```

Comment: tnx, what i was looking for :)